# I need SQLBase documentation

Tags: documentation, opentext, guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase

I am using Open Text SQLBase and I need the official documentation.

I have the documentation (called "SQLBase Language Reference") for the version 11.7 but I need it for version **12.2**.

I search for it in https://www.opentext.com but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLBase documentation ( all versions )  :   [Go Here: All SQLBase Manuals](https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_Books/)

SQLBase Release Notes: [Go Here:  SQLBase Release Notes](https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/SqlBase_ReleaseNotes/)

SQLBase Compatibility Matrix: [Go Here: SQLBase Compatibility Matrix](https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=SqlBase/Documents/)

Join our 'Team Developer SQLWindows Community Forum' and go to the 'SQLBase and Connectivity' section here ( register and you get more options ):  [Go Here: SQLBase User Forum](https://forum.tdcommunity.net/viewforum.php?f=15)

Comment: p.s. If you pay GLS ( Gupta Licensing Service ) for SQLBase upgrades and support, you can go here:  https://login.opentext.com/otdsws/login?client_id=My%20Support    for one-to-one priority help from OpenText Gupta themselves, as an alternate option.